# C# Linq - how to create collection of two types using one collection of one type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `List<Category>`

```
public partial class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public int? ImageId { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductImage? Image { get;
        set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

and I want  to create from this a `List<(string, Image)>` by using a single linq expression. How can I do this?

Doing it with multiple instructions would look like this:

```
List<Category> CategoriesWithImages = Context.Categories.Include(c => c.Image).ToList();
List<(string, Image)> values = new List<(string, Image)>();
CategoriesWithImages.ForEach(c => values.Add((c.Name, Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(c.Image.Image)))));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: Unfortunately **I have to use Include()** method for this to load images from another table

Comment: Would `values = CategoriesWithImages.Select(c => (c.Name, Image.FromStream(...))).ToList()` fit your needs?

Comment: @BradleyUffner but it is possible to create `List<Tuple>` so you are able to create `List<(T1, T2)>`

Comment: I see what you are asking for now. I've edited your question to show you want `List<(string, Image)>` instead of `List<string, Image>`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code seems to be trying to read an image and its name from the database. This has little to do with combining lists - there are no lists here to begin with. It also uses a **very** inefficient way of loading those images. If you want to export images you don't need the `Image` class at all. If you want to display images in a desktop app you only need a *single* image object to display the current image. `Image` objects are very expensive. You don't even need to load the entire image bytes in memory

Comment: Which database are you using? With SQL Server and other databases you can load binary data using a Stream. Instead of loading everything in memory you could read each image as a stream only when you need to use it. Instead of loading the entire table in memory you may be able to only load eg 4KB at a time.

Comment: `Unfortunately I have to use Include() method for this to load images from another table` no you don't. EF will load any related data automatically if it's used in the `Select` clause. `db.Categories.Select(c=>new {c.Name,c.Image.Image})` will load only the name and image bytes. EF Core will generate the JOIN between the Cagtegories and Images table automatically

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos MSSQL. So I'm trying to get images (one image is something like 15KB) from DB to display them in the app. I keep the loaded images in memory because it is highly probable that the user will be asking for all of them every 20s and joining the table of images and table of Categories takes time. I'm using `Include()` because the Image property was empty when I was trying to only select it.

Comment: You need `Include()` because you load the entire object without telling EF you really need the `Image.Image` property. If you use the correct SQL query you'll get what you want directly. The join will be performed by EF, not you. In fact, if you use `ToDictionary(c=>c.Name,c=>c.Image.Image)` you'll get a dictionary of names to bytes you can use as needed

Comment: Is this a desktop or web app? Which stack? What does `the user will be asking for all of them every 20s` mean? How many images are really needed each time? It's important. `Image` and all objects in the `System.Drawing` namespace are only meant to draw on screens in desktop applications. They use limited system-wide GDI resources.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is desktop app windows forms. `the user will be asking for all of them every 20s` means that the application will be disposing and recreating controls on whith the images are displayed. I need to display ALL images from DB that are assigned to `Categories`, it will be no more than 20.

Comment: Display how? A scrolling list? Carousel? Tiles? Or one at a time? Why not store the files on disk and let WinForms use them through eg an ImageList? You can load the files as `Bitmap` objects from a path.

Comment: Some UI controls use virtualization and only load and render what can actually be displayed on screen. This reduces flickering and stuttering along with reducing memory usage

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was thinking about storing the images on the driver and getting those from the path but then the problem with the update would occur. I mean if I have images stored in DB then I can update those images and on all devices, those images will be changed. If I store them on disk then I will have to update the files in the app. So I decided that easier will be storing it in DB

Comment: That doesn't mean you have to load them from memory directly. You can cache them locally in a temporary folder and use `Bitmap(path)` to load them for display.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
List<(string, Image)> values = CategoriesWithImages
    .Select(c => new ValueTuple<string, Image>(c.Name, Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(c.Image.Image))))
    .ToList();
```

Using records is another option (requires C# 9+):

```
List<ImageData> values = CategoriesWithImages
    .Select(c => new ImageData(c.Name, Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(c.Image.Image))))
    .ToList();

record struct ImageData(string Name, Image Image);
```

Note: [structy records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/record-structs) require C# 10+

Comment: Nothing is gained by using struct records or tuples. The code is loading the entire table in memory when all it needs is just the name and bytes. `db.Categories.Select(c=>new {c.Name,c.Image.Image})` would load just that.

Comment: Oh sure, @PanagiotisKanavos! I was just adding another option. I don't think it's correct to assume you could just use an anonymous type here, because the context of the question is not enough to know if you'd want to return the result of this query to an outer scope/caller, in which case an anonymous type won't cut it.

Comment: On the contrary, you have to avoid loading the entire table in memory. That means `Select`ing only the properties that are really needed. Whether the output is an anonymous type, record or plain class doesn't matter. Structs cause problems because their contents are copied by value though, and that includes `byte[]` arrays

Answer (score 0):

Right now `Context.Categories.Include(c => c.Image)` loads the entire `Categories` and probably `Images` tables in memory. That's wasteful

A better way would be to retrieve only the necessary fields from the database and *not* use `Image`. This class, like all types in the `System.Drawing` namespace, is only meant for drawing on a desktop screen using GDI+ and uses limited OS-wide resources. That's why there's no `Image.FromBytes` - the image is expected to be stored on the local disk or get loaded from the application's resources.

From the comments, it seems there are ~20 thumbnails, 15KB each, displayed in a Windows Forms application.

A LINQ query can load just the name and images as `byte[]` arrays, in a dictionary or List, depending on usage:

```
record MyImage(string Name,byte[] Content);

...

var categoryThumbnails=await Context.Categories
    .ToListAsync(new MyImage(c.Name,c.Image.Image));
```

or

```
Dictionary<string,byte[]> categoryThumbnails=await Context.Categories
        .ToDictionaryAsync(c=>c.Name,c=>c.Image.Image));
```

EF Core will generate the necessary JOINs between Categories and the Image table and load only the `Name` and `Image` properties.

At this point, a good idea would be to store the images locally, eg in a temporary folder, and load them from disk with the Image-derived [Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-drawing-bitmap-ctor(system-string)) class and the `Bitmap(string)` constructor.